# Apache Spark - How to count similar key/value pair in Paired RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have `rdd` of type `RDD[(String, String)]`:

**Input RDD:**

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("java", "perl"),(".Net", "php"),("java","perl")))

(java, perl)
(.Net, php)
(java, perl)
```

I want output `RDD[(String, String, Int)]` where the third item in the tuple will be the count of similar sets. e.g:

**Output RDD:**

```
(java, perl, 2)
(.Net, php, 1)
```

I tried adding one to each record in the input RDD, then reducing by key to get the count:

```
val t = rdd.map { case (a,b) => (a,b,1) }
(java, perl, 1)
(.Net, php, 1)
(java, perl, 1)
```

But `t.reduceByKey((a,b,c) => (a,b,c))` is giving an error:

```
value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Int)]
t.reduceByKey((a,b,c) => (a,b,c))
```

I will also be converting the output RDD to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new key by joining the two values and then add as show below:

```python
lines = sc.parallelize(["java, perl", ".Net, php", "java, perl"])
splitted = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
processed = splitted.map(lambda l: (l[0] + "," + l[1], 1))
reduced = processed.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

Or simply treat the whole line as "key":

```python
lines = sc.parallelize(["java, perl", ".Net, php", "java, perl"])
processed = lines.map(lambda l: (l, 1))
reduced = processed.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> lines.collect()
['java, perl', '.Net, php', 'java, perl']
>>> reduced.collect()
[('.Net, php', 1), ('java, perl', 2)]
```

**EDIT:**

You can define a function to format the data and use the `map` transformation:

```
def formatter(line):
    skills = line[0].split()
    return skills[0], skills[1], line[1]

threecols = reduced.map(formatter)
```

Comment: Thanks orions for the reply. Actually I need output to be shown in dataframe. If I Will covert your output to dataframe using df() function, than two columns Will be generated, but I need output in three columns.  Column 1 skill1 (java),columns 2  skill2 (perl), column 3 count (int).